# Cannot Enable EWF on Windows Embedded Standard

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Hi we bought a HP PC with  MS Windows Embedded Standard-HP Customized and we have a problem with enabling the EWF function. If I try to check the EWF status with EMF Manager:

```
ewfmgr c:
```

I get error:

```
“Failed getting protected volume configuration with error 1.  incorrect function.”
```

If I try to enable EWF with commad:

```
ewfmgr c -enable
```

I get error:

```
Failed opening the target device \\.\c with error 2
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried to use HP utility - HP Write Filter Configuration to enable EWF.

But when I enabled EWF with this utility, restart PC and EWF is disable.

Only FBWF is working.

What can be bad? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In modes other than "Reg RAM", EWF needs a special version of the Windows bootloader (NTLDR) and some unpartitioned disk space for creating an overlay volume. I don't know whether your HP PC has been configured with those.

There are some EWF system requirements listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb499124.aspx

EWF usually creates its overlay volume during the First Boot Agent (FBA) process. You could check fbalog.txt for errors. There are some instructions for reconstructing an EWF volume here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913271(WinEmbedded.5).aspx

The file not found error may be due to a missing '`:`' in your second command.

Try `ewfmgr c: -enable` instead.

Comment: So If I want use EWF in disk mode must I have 2 partion? One C: on Windows and second maybe D: for storing data ? With only one partition C: will not EWF working? 2 partion is needed? Tommorow I try this correct version of command but I think I will get some error because if I used this command: **`ewfmgr c:`** I got this error: *“Failed getting protected volume configuration with error 1. incorrect function.”* For example FBWF workings good. I have problem only with EWF.

Comment: EWF creates its own partition/volume, usually during the First Boot Agent (FBA) process. You need to leave some unpartitioned disk space for this.

Comment: But, First I have only C partition, I disable EWF, use partition manager decrease size of partiton C and create new partion D. Maybe I deleted EWF partition? It is possible check if EWF partition exist. Maybe renew this partion with rundll32.exe ewfdll.dll,ConfigureEwf. If if possible some code example.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but it came up in my search so I thought I would leave my answer.

When I encountered this error it was because I had restored an image using imeagex. I didn't run sysprep before taking the backup image. I wiped and recreated the partition which updated the partition signature which confused EWF enough to make it not work.

EWF doesn't have a nice tool to configure the protected volumes. So I wrote one. Here's the source.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400

#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <tchar.h>

const TCHAR VOL_PATH[] = TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\ewf\\Parameters\\Protected\\Volume%i");

VOID Usage(){

    _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: ewfvoladd <Drive Letter> <Volume Number>\n"));

}

INT _tmain(INT iArgCount, LPCTSTR pszArgVals[]){

    INT iReturn = 0;

    if (iArgCount == 3){

        TCHAR szDrive[MAX_PATH];

        _sntprintf_s(szDrive,MAX_PATH,TEXT("\\\\.\\%s:"),pszArgVals[1]);
        szDrive[MAX_PATH-1] = 0;

        HANDLE hPartition = CreateFile(szDrive,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,nullptr,OPEN_EXISTING,0,nullptr);

        if (hPartition != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

            PARTITION_INFORMATION piPartInfo = {};

            DWORD dwSize = sizeof(piPartInfo);

            if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition,IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO,nullptr,0,&piPartInfo,dwSize,&dwSize,nullptr)){

                dwSize = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION) + sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION) * 9;

                LPBYTE pbDrive = new BYTE [ dwSize ];

                ZeroMemory(pbDrive,dwSize);

                DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION *pdliDrive = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION*)pbDrive;

                if (DeviceIoControl(hPartition,IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT,nullptr,0,pdliDrive,dwSize,&dwSize,nullptr)){

                    TCHAR szVol[MAX_PATH];

                    _sntprintf_s(szVol,MAX_PATH,VOL_PATH,(INT)_ttol(pszArgVals[2]));
                    szVol[MAX_PATH-1] = 0;

                    HKEY hVol = nullptr;

                    LONG lRegErr = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,szVol,0,nullptr,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_WRITE,nullptr,&hVol,nullptr);

                    if (lRegErr == ERROR_SUCCESS){

                        const DWORD dwZero = 0,
                                    dwOne = 1,
                                    dwTwo = 2;

                        lRegErr = RegSetValueEx(hVol,TEXT("Type"),0,REG_DWORD,(LPCBYTE)&dwTwo,sizeof(dwTwo));

                        if (lRegErr != ERROR_SUCCESS){

                            iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to set Type: %i\n"),iReturn);

                        }

                        lRegErr = RegSetValueEx(hVol,TEXT("Enabled"),0,REG_DWORD,(LPCBYTE)&dwZero,sizeof(dwZero));

                        if (lRegErr != ERROR_SUCCESS){

                            iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to set Enabled: %i\n"),iReturn);

                        }

                        lRegErr = RegSetValueEx(hVol,TEXT("CompareBeforeAlloc"),0,REG_DWORD,(LPCBYTE)&dwOne,sizeof(dwOne));

                        if (lRegErr != ERROR_SUCCESS){

                            iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to set CompareBeforeAlloc: %i\n"),iReturn);

                        }

                        lRegErr = RegSetValueEx(hVol,TEXT("DiskSignature"),0,REG_DWORD,(LPCBYTE)&pdliDrive->Signature,sizeof(pdliDrive->Signature));

                        if (lRegErr != ERROR_SUCCESS){

                            iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to set DiskSignature: %i\n"),iReturn);

                        }

                        lRegErr = RegSetValueEx(hVol,TEXT("PartitionOffset"),0,REG_QWORD,(LPCBYTE)&piPartInfo.StartingOffset.QuadPart,sizeof(piPartInfo.StartingOffset.QuadPart));

                        if (lRegErr != ERROR_SUCCESS){

                            iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to set PartitionOffset: %i\n"),iReturn);

                        }

                        RegCloseKey(hVol);

                    }else{

                        iReturn = (INT)lRegErr;

                        _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to open registry key (%s): %i\n"),szVol,iReturn);

                    }

                }else{

                    iReturn = (INT)GetLastError();

                    _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to get disk info: %i\n"),iReturn);

                }

                delete [] pbDrive;

            }else{

                iReturn = (INT)GetLastError();

                _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to get partition info: %i\n"),iReturn);

            }

            CloseHandle(hPartition);

        }else{

            iReturn = (INT)GetLastError();

            _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to open drive: %i\n"),iReturn);

        }

    }else{

        iReturn = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

        Usage();

        _tprintf(TEXT("\nNot enough parameters\n"));

    }

    return iReturn;

}
```

So, if you only have 1 partition and it's the C: drive you would run the following and reboot.

```
ewfvoladd c 0
```

Then you should be able to enable EWF like so

```
ewfmgr c: -enable
```

Reboot again and you're done.